# _splitpath_s: wrong argument type?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Given the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    char dir[_MAX_DIR];
    char fname[_MAX_FNAME];
    char ext[_MAT_EXT];
    _splitpath_s( argv[0], drive, dir, fname, ext);
    // ...some more code...
}
```

The compiler throws the following error:

> error 2665: '_splitpath_s' none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

What is going wrong? I'm using VS 2010 SP1.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is this a UNICODE build? If so, your first argument will be a `wchar_t`, which will give such an error. You've also omitted all of the `size_t` arguments.

Comment: At least one of the parameters you are passing to _splitpath_s is the wrong type.

Comment: You mean the character set? Yes it is.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `_tsplitpath_s`.

Comment: @RogerRowland:  There is a (C++ only) overload that takes references to arrays.  The size arguments are not required for that overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `_UNICODE` is defined, then `_TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, so `argv[0]` is a `wchar_t*`, which is not convertible to `char const*` (this is the type of the first parameter of `_splitpath_s`.

The Error List in Visual Studio only shows the first line of each error, for brevity.  The full error from the compiler, which you can find in the Output window, is more informative:

```
error C2665: '_splitpath_s' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
    [...]\stdlib.h(797): could be 'errno_t _splitpath_s<3,256,256,256>(const char *,char (&)[3],char (&)[256],char (&)[256],char (&)[256]) throw()'
    while trying to match the argument list '(_TCHAR *, char [3], char [256], char [256], char [256])'
```

In the full error, it is obvious that the only argument whose type *might* not match is the first one, since the others clearly match.

If you are going to use `_TCHAR`, then use it and its friends everywhere.  Your arrays should be arrays of `_TCHAR` and you should use `_tsplitpath_s`.  Alternatively, don't use `_TCHAR` at all and just use either narrow or wide character strings throughout your project (on Windows, wide strings are preferable)

Comment: ..alright. And to make it more comprehensive to guys like me [some basic informations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc)

Comment: You might want to add the hint to look in the Output window to see the full error message.  Programmers often don't know to look there to get the better message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C, then

```
/* _splitpath(path_buffer, drive, dir, fname, ext); */
_splitpath_s(path_buffer, drive, _MAX_DRIVE, dir, 
             _MAX_DIR, fname, _MAX_FNAME, ext, _MAX_EXT);
```

If using C++, there isn't any reason to use `_tmain` if you are not using `_TCHAR` for `drive`, `dir`, etc or you should be using `_tsplitpath_s` instead. Or convert all of them to ANSI or UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
wchar_t dir[_MAX_DIR] = {0};
wchar_t drive[_MAX_DRIVE] = {0};
wchar_t fname[_MAX_FNAME] = {0};
wchar_t ext[_MAX_EXT] = {0};
errno_t err;

std::wstring path = L"c:\\this\\is\\a\\test.exe";

err = _wsplitpath_s(path.c_str(),&drive[0],_MAX_DRIVE,&dir[0],_MAX_DIR,&fname[0],_MAX_FNAME,&ext[0],_MAX_EXT);
```